# Slider Doesn't Update to Maximum Value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, slider

I have a text-box binded to a slider.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=maxValue, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="30" Height="25" BorderBrush="Transparent" PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown"></TextBox>
<Slider Value="{Binding TotalSize}" Maximum="{Binding MaxMaxBackupSize, Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="{Binding MinBackupSize}" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="2" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Name="maxValue"></Slider>
```

After a user chooses something, I recalculate the Maximum (MaxMaxBackupSize), since it's a property binded, this should update the textbox and the slider, however, for some reason - only the textbox value gets changed, and if it was higher then the maximum, gets lowered to the maximum. The slider however seems to be left untouched, and I can still move it as I wish (and this also changes the text in the textbox...

I have the following relevant properties:

```
private int totalSize;

public int TotalSize
{
    get { return totalSize; }
    set
    {
        if (value == totalSize)
            return;

        totalSize = value;
        ConfigChanged = true;
        ChangeIni = true;
    }
}

public static int MaxMaxBackupSize { get; set; }
public static int MinBackupSize { get; set; }
```

The change that being made after user press a lever is:

```
...
MaxMaxBackupSize = Convert.ToInt16(f / 1000000000)
TotalSize = (TotalSize < MaxMaxBackupSize) ? TotalSize : MaxMaxBackupSize;
...
```

UPDATE0: (BTW, I'm using a nuget package called Fody.OnPropertyChanged that saves me the need to raise onpropertychanged - so this is not the reason)

**UPDATE: I should be clear on what I'm saying when I mean the slider doesn't change - the slider does shift, but the maximum value of the slider remains the old maximum value. Say if before the maximum value was 50, and now its 20, if the slider was previously on 30 then it will shift to 20, but I will still have the ability to move it until 50. I want the maximum to be capped at 20. Not sure if it's possible at all, or not.**

***UPDATE2: for now I found a workaround, to check if the value is bigger than the max in the property, and if so it pops up a message box saying it's not possible, and returns.***

Comment: Please provide a minimal repo when you ask a question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is missing? Maybe just the change I make after the user chooses something... I'll add it.

Comment: @Sameed Read the post - I'm using a special package that implements them for me, and it works perfect. This is not the issue.

Comment: @Sameed Maybe my question wasn't clear - please check the update in bold

Comment: Are you sure the PropertyChanged is triggered with Fody on static Properties? Could you just try if it works, when the MaxMaxBackupSize Property is not static (some kind of workaround)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem seems to be the static Properties, as the NotifyPropertyChanged can only be called on a instance, so to make it work you would have to implement it as a static Member, with a non-static accessor like

```
private static int _maxBackupSize;
public int MaxBackupSize
{ 
  get { return _maxBackupSize; }
  set { _maxBackupSize = value; <However your Framework raises the Event> }
}
```

Now you can have a static variable with a non-static accessor which can raise the NotifyPropertyChanged event